# Use scipy lognormal distribution to fit data with small values, then show in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I have a data set which contains values from 0 to 1e-5. I guess the data can be described by lognormal distribution. So I use scipy.stats.lognorm to fit my data and want to plot the origin data and the fitting distribution on a same figure by using matplotlib.

Firstly, I plot the sample by histogram:
[image]

Then, I add the fitting distribution by line plot. However, this will change the Y-axis to a very large number:
[image]

So the origin data (sample) cannot be seen on the figure!

I've check all variables and I found that the variable `pdf_fitted` is so large (>1e7). I really don't understand why a simple fit `scistats.lognorm.fit` to a sample that was generated by the same distribution `scistats.lognorm.pdf` doesn't work. Here is the codes to demonstrate my problem:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats as scistats
import numpy as np

# generate a sample for x between 0 and 1e-5
x = np.linspace(0, 1e-5, num=1000)
y = scistats.lognorm.pdf(x, 3, loc=0, scale=np.exp(10))
h = plt.hist(y, bins=40) # plot the sample by histogram
# plt.show()

# fit the sample by using Log Normal distribution
param = scistats.lognorm.fit(y)
print("Log-normal distribution parameters : ", param)
pdf_fitted = scistats.lognorm.pdf(
    x, *param[:-2], loc=param[-2], scale=param[-1])
plt.plot(x, pdf_fitted, label="Fitted Lognormal distribution")
plt.ticklabel_format(style='sci', scilimits=(-3, 4), axis='x')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: You forgot to specify the x-values of the `plot(x_values,y_values)`

Comment: matplotlib has [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/api/two_scales.html) for plotting with different scales

Comment: Hi, that can only change the X-axis in figure. But, I still don't understand why  `pdf_fitted` is so large ...

Comment: Your whole approach is wrong. Your histogram isn't a histogram of data drawn from a lognormal distribution, and you're fitting to garbage data, which produces a garbage fit. There's an example of the correct way to get what you want using your current parameters in my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## The problem

The immediate problem that you're having is that your fit is really, really bad. You can see this if you set the x and y scale on the plot to log, like with `plt.xscale('log')` and `plt.yscale('log')`. This lets you see both your histogram and your fitted data on a single plot:

[image]

so it's off by many orders of magnitude in both directions.

## The fix

Your whole approach to generating a sample from the probability distribution represented by `stats.lognorm` and fitting it was wrong. Here's a correct way to do it, using the same parameters for the lognorm distribution that you supplied in your question:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats as scistats
import numpy as np

plt.figure(figsize=(12,7))
realparam = [.1, 0, np.exp(10)]

# generate pdf data around the mean value
m = realparam[2]
x = np.linspace(m*.6, m*1.4, num=10000)
y = scistats.lognorm.pdf(x, *realparam)

# generate a matching random sample
sample = scistats.lognorm.rvs(*realparam, size=100000)
# plot the sample by histogram
h = plt.hist(sample, bins=100, density=True)

# fit the sample by using Log Normal distribution
param = scistats.lognorm.fit(sample)
print("Log-normal distribution parameters : ", param)
pdf_fitted = scistats.lognorm.pdf(x, *param)
plt.plot(x, pdf_fitted, lw=5, label="Fitted Lognormal distribution")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Output:

```
Log-normal distribution parameters :  (0.09916091013245995, -215.9562383088556, 22245.970148671593)
```

[image]

Comment: So, does this means that I can't use lognormal to fit a sample that has small values ? But I do really generate the sample by lognormal distribution `scistats.lognorm.pdf`, I don't understand why the inverse way `scistats.lognorm.fit` doesn't work.

Comment: You seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding of what a pdf is. A pdf is not a sample. Taking a small slice of the pdf (which is how you're getting your `y` data) is not the same thing as taking a sample from the pdf. Taking the integral of the pdf over a given region tells you the probability that a sample will be drawn from that region. That is what a pdf is. In order to take samples from the distributions in `scipy.stats`, you has to use their `rvs` method.

Comment: Hi tel, thanks to your clear answer, I've marked your post as the solution and add more details about my true confusion in my origin post *_*